# Load a map through an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a game that requires a tile map saved in multidimensional array.  In my game I have all of these maps made that are NSStrings with all the saved values needed, I'm looking to save all the 256 values of the NSString into an int 16x16 multidimensional array.

Here is my current code however it doesn't work

```
-(void)LoadMap:(NSString*)mapString
{
    for(int h = 0; h < kMapSize; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < kMapSize; w++)
        {
            map[w][h] = [[mapString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((h)+(w*kMapSize), 1)] intValue];
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be great thankyou :)

Comment: What happens instead of what you expect? Runtime exceptions? Compilation errors? Incorrect resulting data? BSOD? Pig flyings? Run by fruitings? Often the key to figuring out programming problems lies in the specific details regarding how something "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you asking about how to tokenize each value off the NSString and use that in your multi array?

Comment: There is a run time error saying that the substring with range is trying to get data that is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential errors:

- `kMapSize` is possibly not equal to 16. This variable has a misleading name since the casual reader would think it should be 256. Perhaps rename it `kMapWidth`.
- `mapString` is possibly not 256 characters long. You might want to check `[mapString length]` at the beginning of `LoadMap`.

Comment: i feel very stupid but yes the string was shorter than 256 characters

Answer (score 1):

Below code works without problem. Maybe the second row is the reason of error.

```
// initial data
NSInteger kMapSize = 3;
char map[3][3];   <-- this row ?
NSString *mapString = @"000111222";

// put initial data into 'map' array
for(int h = 0; h < kMapSize; h++) {
    for(int w = 0; w < kMapSize; w++) {
        map[w][h] = [[mapString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((h)+(w*kMapSize), 1)] intValue];
    }
}

// confirm whether the data is stored successfully
for (int h = 0; h < kMapSize; h++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < kMapSize; w++) {
        NSLog(@"%d", map[w][h]);
    }
}
```